# Issue occurs while publishing app to PlayStore

Tags: android, release, google-play-console, production, targetsdkversion

I have a problem while uploading the app to the Play console. The project was developed and published 3 years back and published to Play Store. After that, we haven't worked on that project. Now due to the new policy to update every app to sdk version 33, we have updated that code. While uploading the app to the Play Store it shows showing error:

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):

```
SHA1: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK that you uploaded have fingerprint(s):

```
SHA1: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

(note: we don't have the old PC that we used to upload this app to the Play Store. we are trying this with a new PC)

[image]

Is it possible to fix this issue .

Comment: Do you have the JKS file that was used to generate SHA1? Is it the same one that was used 3 years back?

Comment: Did you upload apk and *not* app bundle 3 years ago?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal yeah i have the jks file and I generated the apk using that jks file

Comment: @VladGuriev we upload apk on that day

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate way to solve this is to reach out the google support team.

- Go to your Play developer console and click on the little "?" button on the navbar.
- Now Click on contact us and write "Upload Key Reset Request"

In reply, they’ll ask you to generate a new `keystore` and `certificate.pem` file.

Generate those files and send them back.